# test for existence of column before calling collection->setOrder

Tags: magento2

I have seen that we can add one line to the magento core code that will add a secondary sort to product listings, like so:

`/magento-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php`
~line 192

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    $this->_collection->setOrder('name','asc');
    //^^^^^ this is my added line ^^^^^^^
}
```

Despite the fact that it is a no-no to alter to core magento code, this works just great.  Until I added an extension which steals the product toolbar from magento-catalog as a control for its own grid.  Since there is no 'name' column in that select, magento crashes on my ill-advised line.

Is there a way I can test to see if name is valid before I call setOrder?  If I can figure something out, maybe I'll move my code off to a plugin/extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    if ($this->_collection->getFirstItem()->getName()){
        $this->_collection->setOrder('name','asc');
    }
}
```

Comment: Curiously I have tried to inspect the collection a number of times in different ways.  It seems that once it's been accessed, the setOrder function seems to have no effect.  I tried your suggestion, and though it returns true, the sort by is not applied.  I am guessing that is because it must execute the select in order to look at the collection contents, and then it's too late.  Is there a way to inspect the scheme to be used and determine if the name column is in there?

Comment: Nobody? Has any ideas?

Comment: There is a way to do that actually. You can use the function `getSelect()` on the collection and it will give you the raw sql statement.

Comment: Wonderful!  I'll give this a try today.  If you put this in a separate answer, I can give you points if it works (just sayin').

Comment: Okay! Let me know if it works!

Comment: I actually just found a function `addAttributeToSort()`. Try adding `addAttributeToSort('name')` before the `setOrder` line inside the if statement

Comment: Also, if you want to get the columns being selected you can use the function `->getPart('columns')` off of `getSelect()` so... `_collection->getSelect()->getPart('columns')`

Comment: Well, unfortunately none of those worked.  The sql never had any order by clause regardless of whether I asked for it before or after using setOrder.  However, your hints about looking at the sql were huge (->getSelect()->__toString was a big help).  I was able to move on and come at this problem from an entirely different angle afterward.  (I removed the product toolbar from the offending solution code and applied a sort directly to the collection instead of through the toolbar.